# How to write automated interactive shell script?

Tags: shell, expect

I just want to write a shell script for automatic feeding the username and password prompts when running my commands,
I tried this one but it did not work. Please help me for any way out.

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/expect

ls -ltr

spawn sudo git pull

expect "[sudo] password for sandeep:"

send "sandeep123\n"

expect "Username :"

send "sandeep\n"

expect "Password :"

send "sandeep121\n"
```

I am getting following output :

```
sandeep@K2-Sandeep-08:~$ ./checkout.sh 
total 64
./checkout.sh: line 8: spawn: command not found
couldn't read file "Username:": no such file or directory
./checkout.sh: line 16: send: command not found
couldn't read file "Password:": no such file or directory
./checkout.sh: line 20: send: command not found
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for expect is

```
expect -c 'spawn sudo git pull; expect assword; send "password\n"; interact'
```

Where `spawn sudo git pull;` is your command, `expect assword;` waits for `assword` to appear and when it does `expect` sends `password`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two #! lines, but your script can only be run by one of these programs at once.  Since most of your commands are Expect commands, delete the `#!/bin/bash` line so the script gets run by Expect.  However the line `ls -ltr` is not an Expect command and will cause an error, but you can work around this by converting it to `puts [exec ls -ltr]`.  For more detail see [the Expect manual page](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.5/expect/expect.1.html)